# Does the standard library have a way to check the equality of two templated types' base template type?

Tags: c++, c++17, type-traits, template-templates

Having trouble coming up with the correct terminology to search for this adequately, but does the standard library have something to test for the same base template type?

```
template <typename T>
struct foo {};

template <typename T>
struct bar {};

static_assert(std::is_same_base_type<foo<int>, foo<float>>::value == 1);
static_assert(std::is_same_base_type<foo<int>, bar<int>>::value == 0);
```

Comment: Terminology note: "base template type" is not the phrase you want to use, and "base type" is *definitely* the wrong term. The latter strongly suggests inheritance. The question you're asking is whether they are instantiations of the same template. And it's also probably not a good idea to ask for this.

Comment: @NicolBolas yeah I knew "base" was the wrong term, but don't know of the term for a type without its template arguments. Also, in this case, I'm doing some DSL work where I need to enforce that a specific template type is passed to a variadic template argument list. Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: "*but don't know of the term for a type without its template arguments*" It's just a "template". Or if you need to be specific about the kind of template, a "type template". That is, `vector` is a type template. `vector<int>` is not a template; it is the product of template substitution, but `vector<int>` is otherwise a regular type just like any other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the standard library?

No, as far I know.

But is trivial to write it.

```
template <typename, typename>
struct is_same_template : public std::false_type
 { };

template <template <typename> class C, typename T, typename U>
struct is_same_template<C<T>, C<U>> : public std::true_type
 { };
```

So you can write

```
static_assert( true == is_same_template<foo<int>, foo<float>>::value, "!" ) ;
static_assert( false == is_same_template<foo<int>, bar<int>>::value, "!" );
```

The problem of this solution is that the specialization works only for template-template bases receiving only one template type parameter.

You can improve it, for bases (template-template arguments) receiving a variadic list of arguments

```
template <template <typename...> class C,
          typename ... Ts, typename ... Us>
struct is_same_template<C<Ts...>, C<Us...>> : public std::true_type
 { };
```

but this doesn't works to check, by examples, `std::array`

```
static_assert( true == is_same_template<std::array<int, 3u>,
                                        std::array<float, 5u>>::value, "!" ) ;
```

For `std::array` you have to add another specialization

```
template <template <typename, std::size_t> class C,
          typename T1, std::size_t S1, typename T2, std::size_t S2>
struct is_same_template<C<T1, S1>, C<T2, S2>> : public std::true_type
 { };
```

Unfortunately there are innumerable possible template-template signatures so you have to add innumerable `is_same_template` specializations.

This is the reason (I suppose) there isn't a standard library type-traits.

Comment: Yes, the simple case is trivial. But the fully generic case seems impossible...

Comment: Is there a term for the nested template arguments?

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED - sorry but I don't understand what you mean; in my answer, which ones are the "nested template arguments"?

Comment: @max66 `template <template <typename...> class C>` the nested `template` is what I'm referring to - what is the term for that?

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED - if you mean the `template <typename...> class C` (but also `template <typename, std::size_t> class C` in another example) it's called "template-template parameter".

Comment: @Deduplicator - to solve generically this problem we need a sort of `auto`-with-steroids: an `auto` that can intercept types, values and template-template parameters. Unfortunately there isn't in current C++.